# Do union and rank operators commute?

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\rank{rank}\def\union{{\textstyle\bigcup}}$

The rank of a well founded set is defined recursively as $\rank x = \union\{\rank y +1 : y \in x\}$. It would be nice if $\rank\union x$ were just $\union\rank x$. However, I couldn't find it mentioned anywhere and that's why I'm asking here. Here's an outline of my reasoning.
\begin{align*}
α∈\rank\union x &\iff (∃z∈\union x)(α∈ \rank z+1)&\text{by def. of $\rank$}\\ 
&\iff (∃y∈x)(∃z∈y)(α∈ \rank z +1) &\text{by def. of $\union$}\\
&\iff (∃y∈x)(α∈ \rank y)&\text{by def. of $\rank$}\\
&\iff (∃y∈x)(α+1∈ \rank y+1)& α<β\text{ iff }α+1<β+1\\
&\iff α+1∈ \rank x &\text{by def. of $\rank$}\\
&\iff α ∈ \union\rank x.  &α+1<γ\text{ iff } ∃β(α<β<γ)
\end{align*}
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that rank commutes with unions, although I think the last step of your proof requires *slightly* more justification than simply saying 'by definition of $\bigcup$'.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited accordingly to your suggestion.